# Ctrl+Left/Right moves focus to other control

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, focus, keyboard-events

I have a WinForms usercontrol (ZedGraphControl) hosted on a WindowsFormsHost WPF control, placed in a nested Grid. When I attempt to handle Ctrl+Left/Right in the WinForms control code the control looses focus, and focus moves to control in the grid cell to the Left/Right.

What may cause this, and how can the behavior be disabled?

**Edit:** The behavior is triggered if a DataGrid is in the grid cell to the left or right, with cells displayed that can take focus. Also if a TextBox is there, possibly any control that can take editable focus.

Comment: Is it Ctrl+Left/Right or Ctrl+Alt+Left/Right that moves the focus?

Comment: @MikeStrobel Yes it seems to be only Ctrl+Left.

Comment: Above comment was wrong, it reacts to Ctrl+Left/Right (see edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like something in your WPF universe is intercepting those key combinations and using them to move focus.  At first, I thought it might be WPF's built-in directional keyboard navigation, but based on your edits, I think it might be something else.

Whatever is happening, you might be able to prevent it by overriding some keyboard processing behavior in `WindowsFormsHost`.

```
public class WindowsFormsHostEx : WindowsFormsHost
{
    protected override bool TranslateAcceleratorCore(ref MSG msg, ModifierKeys modifiers)
    {
        const int vkLeft = 0x25;
        const int vkRight = 0x27;

        if (modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control &&
            ((int)msg.wParam == vkLeft || (int)msg.wParam == vkRight))
        {
            var m = Message.Create(msg.hwnd, msg.message, msg.wParam, msg.lParam);
            this.Child?.WindowTarget?.OnMessage(ref m);
            return true;
        }

        return base.TranslateAcceleratorCore(ref msg, modifiers);
    }
}
```

Based on my tests, this causes the `WindowsFormsHostEx` to 'claim' all <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left/Right</kbd> keystrokes when the host has focus.  It dispatches them to the hosted WinForms content, with WPF apparently carrying on as if the event never happened.

Comment: Sorry I was mistaken about Right/Left, due to my layout. If I have a DataGrid with cells displayed that can take focus or be edited, or a TextBox, either on right or left, the focus moves as described, to either side, by Ctrl+ Left or Right. Will test your code.

Comment: @bretddog In that case, I updated my answer to handle both Ctrl+Left and Ctrl+Right.